# How does c++ or c# work with com ports?

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port

I am working on an exercise where I need to send the following bytes of data "0x80, 0x07, 0x52, 0x1f, 0x1f

How would I go through with this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/

[Communicating with Serial Port in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/serialportcommunication12082008111137am/serialportcommunication.aspx)